# $injector:modulerr Failed to instantiate module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm new to AngularJS and I face this exception

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module MovieRama due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   Failed to instantiate module MovieRama.services due to: Error:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'MovieRama.services' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>   a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

My code is:

```
var app = angular.module('MovieRama.services', []);
app.factory('rtAPIservice', function($http) {

    var rtAPI = {};

    rtAPI.getMovies = function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'JSONP',
               url: 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/in_theaters.json?     page_limit=10&page=1&country=us&apikey=XXXXX&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
        });
    }

    return rtAPI;
});

app.factory('rtAPIserviceall', function($http) {
    var rtAPIall = {};

    rtAPIall.getMoviesall = function () {
        return $http({
            method: 'JSONP',
               url: 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json',{
            params: {
                page_limit: '10',
               page:'1',
               q: $scope.search,
               apikey: 'XXXX',
               callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            }
        }
        })
    }
return rtAPIall;
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css">
<title>MovieRama</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="MovieRama">

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th colspan="4">MovieRama</th></tr>
            </thead>


            <tbody ng-if= "search != null" ng-controller="moviesController"> 
            <ul ng-repeat="movie in moviesList">

                 <td>

                    <img src={{movie.posters.thumbnail}} />

                    <ul> {{movie.title}}</ul>
                    <ul> Release: {{movie.year}}- Runime: {{movie.runtime}}-Audience rating: {{movie. ratings.audience_score}}</ul>
                    <ul>{{movie.synopsis}}</ul>

               </td>
</tr>

            </tbody>

            <tbody ng-if="search == null">
            <ul ng-repeat="movie in moviesListall" ng-controller="moviesallController">

                <td>
                    <img src={{movie.posters.thumbnail}}/>
                    <ul> {{movie.title}}</ul>
                    <ul> Release: {{movie.year}} - Runtime: {{movie.runtime}} - Audience rating:      {{movie.ratings.audience_score}} </ul>
                    <ul> {{movie.synopsis}} </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('MovieRama', [
        'MovieRama.controllers',
        'MovieRama.services'
        ]);
```

It works just fine with one factory. What is the problem?

Comment: How are you instantiating the module in your html?

Comment: @AlexChance I edited the description for you

Comment: Just a guess, but you may want to try changing the order you are loading your js files. app.js is loaded first and trying to inject the dependency on MovieRama.services, before it is loaded. Or try to put all the module code in one file to test if that is the issue.

Comment: I tried and nothing changed. The weird thing  is that the exception appears when I add the second app.factory.

Comment: Also, Why have the two methods as different services. You could have One service with two methods as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency `MovieRama.services` to the main module that bootstraps the app (probably `index.js` or `app.js`, based on your file structure) .

Also remove the reference to `<script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>` as you have two files for angular. Move angular files to the top before your `js` files.

Also, Why have the two methods as different services. You could have One service with two methods as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('MovieRama.services', []);
app.factory('rtAPIservice', function($http) {

var rtAPI = {};

rtAPI.getMovies = function() {
    return $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
           url: 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/in_theaters.json?     page_limit=10&page=1&country=us&apikey=XXXXX&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
    });
}
rtAPI.getMoviesall = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
           url: 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json',{
        params: {
            page_limit: '10',
           page:'1',
           q: $scope.search,
           apikey: 'XXXX',
           callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        }
    }
    })
}
return rtAPI;
});
```

Comment: I think I have already done this. I have edited the description for you

Comment: Nothing changed. The weird thing is that the problem appears when i add the second app.factory. Any other ideas?

Comment: No.. No change at all